# How to get UEFA Champions League from fbref using worldfootball R package?

Tags: r, package

I want to get data with teams names, full-time scores and expected goal from this site

https://fbref.com/en/comps/8/2022-2023/schedule/2022-2023-Champions-League-Scores-and-Fixtures

Using `worldfootballR`, I tried:

```
fb_match_results(country = '', gender = 'M', season_end_year = '2023',
  non_dom_league_url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/8/2022-2023/schedule/2022-2023-Champions-League-Scores-and-Fixtures')
```

which then told me `Data not available for the season(s) selected`

And it said `NULL` if I use `fb_match_urls(country = c("UEFA"), gender = "M", season_end_year = '2022')`

I also tried different years and removing the country names but I'm still not able to get the data.

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured it out, the `non_dom_league_url` argument should be `"https://fbref.com/en/comps/8/history/Champions-League-Seasons"`